# "Save configuration to file" IIS 8

Tags: iis-8

I am looking for the "Save configuration to file" function as in IIS 6.0 but in  IIS 8.0?

Tried "Export Server Package" but this failed?

How do you do this? Apologies but I'm a dev really, I'm configuring a new dev machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options:

- [Backup and Restore the configuration](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/24/how-to-backup-restore-iis7-configuration.aspx) (this is for IIS 7 but I believe IIS 8 works similarly)
- [Use Web Deploy to deploy the configuration](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)

If you use IIS in any significant capacity I highly recommend learning Web Deploy, as the Web Farm Framework is based on it, and it makes moving and synchronizing sites and configurations between servers so very much easier than ever before.  It even makes it relatively easy to migration configurations from IIS 6 to 7 to 8.  [Here's what appears to be a decent quick guide](https://www.orcsweb.com/blog/fred/how-to-migrate-all-your-sites-using-web-deploy/) to migrating sites and configuration.